# Why does my socket seem to be closing on the client side even though I keep emitting messages from the server that the client should be listening to?

Tags: python, jquery, html, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a stream of random numbers on a Flask server and then send those through a socket to the html such that a web page keeps updating with a new number. In my code here, I was just trying to make sure I could print to console the numbers I got from the random number generator but after the first number, it seems like the socket closes on one of the sides (either client or server) even though I know that the server keeps sending new numbers every second. So that makes me feel like the client stops listening if I keep emitting a message with a new number every second but I can not find the issue. I am brand new to web development (focus on java in school) but this was a project for work so any help would be awesome!

Since I print every new number generated, I know that my emit statement from the client side MUST be getting hit. But I do not know what is happening on the other side except that no new numbers are being sent to the console so I am assuming the client stops listening at some point.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from random import random
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET KEY'] = 'secrett'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()
class RandomThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):

        self.delay = 1
        super (RandomThread, self).__init__()

    def randomNumberGenerator(self):
       # generate a rnd # every 1 second and emit to socketIO
       print("Making random numbers")
       newNumberCount = 0
       while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
           number = round(random()*10, 3)
           print(number)
           socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': number}, namespace='/')
           sleep(self.delay)
           socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': 6}, namespace='/')
           newNumberCount = newNumberCount + 1
           print(newNumberCount)
       print("did i leave?")
    def run(self):
        self.randomNumberGenerator()

@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')

def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    #Start the random number generator thread only if the thread has not been started before.
    if not thread.isAlive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = RandomThread()
        thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3 style='color: #ccc;font-size: 30px;'>No message yet..</h3>
    <div class="message_holder"></div>

    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="User Name"/>
      <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Messages"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
      socket.on( 'connect', function() {
        socket.emit( 'my event', {
          data: 'User Connected'
        } )
        var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault()
          let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val()
          let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
          socket.emit( 'my event', {
            user_name : user_name,
            message : user_input
          } )
          $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
        } )
      } )


      socket.on( 'newnumber', function( msg ) {
        console.log("Received number" + msg.number);
        //maintain a list of ten numbers
        console.log(msg.number);
      } )

      socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
        console.log( msg )
        if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
          $( 'h3' ).remove()
          $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
        }
      })
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

It should print to console a new number every second, but instead it just prints the first number and nothing else. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am in a similar situation, my jquery client keeps disconnecting from Flask server.